# Jquery Mobile HTML5 iOS native app launching pages back to safari

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with a certain page in **JQM** that does not load when accessed by a link but will load. The page it is calling has some google chart libraries added which seem to be causing the non-loading issue. This problem can be sorted if ajax is disabled using the `data-ajax="false"` command.

Trouble is, when that link is then clicked on when we add the HTML5 as a native app on the iPad, it closes the app and opens safari to display the link.

How is this behavior disabled?

Code is below.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="content" class="ui-grid-b  my-breakpoint" align="center">   
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a href="fridges.php" data-ajax="false"> <img class="icons" border=0 alt="Storage Monitoring" src="Images/Fridge Icon.png"> </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **data-ajax="false"**... It will open in safari because without ajax it's the same as saying the link they click is external (rel="external"). What you need to do is figure out why it's not working without data-ajax="false".

I assume this has to do with one of the many common scripting errors seen with developers using JQM. Most people think they can use JQM with their current web development knowledge without reading the documentation, and this is a big mistake. Not necessarily saying you are, but it's all too common.

The first thing you need to do is post an example and tell us **why** it's not working. You also can't expect everything to magically work with JQM, are these charts supported? If not, you may have to tweak it to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on that. I have read through a lot of the material on the JQM site, but I will drill down some more to figure out why it is not loading.